# In Chrome, how can I right-click to open a javascript link in a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

There's a website I frequently visit, and I'd like to be able to right-click the links on this site and have the option to open them in a new tab in Google Chrome. However, when I do this currently, the tab opens to About:Blank. An example of the code that I am clicking for the link follows:

```
<a id="ctl00_Form" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MORECODE','')">LINK TEXT</a></strong>
```

Is there a way to right-click and open these types of links? If not, is there a way to add this ability in Google Chrome?

Comment: Tried ctrl+click?

Comment: That appears to open the link in the current tab.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround, but I find it works for me in my Chrome version  73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (32-bit):

1. Click the javascript link. The current tab loads the associated page.
2. Duplicate the current tab (native method is to right-click the tab and choose 'Duplicate'). A new tab is opened directly adjacent and to the right of the current tab, it is given focus and becomes the new current tab, and it is a duplicate of the previous tab (down to its history even).
3. Switch back to the previous tab (the one you duplicated), and navigate back one step in history. You now have your first tab at the original page *before* clicking the javascript link, and adjacent to it you have the javascript link.

This layout works for my purposes, although you may find it tedious (depending on the frequency with which you'd need to use it). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't. All you can do is to view the page's source and open the desired link manually.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that I often do is to normally click the javascript link, then cmd+click (or ctrl+click depending on your OS) on the back button so I open the previous page on a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

@Cam

Unfortunately this is the best way to do it. I made it faster and easier by creating a shortcut in `System Settings->Keyboard->App Shortcuts`:

```
Google Chrome.app
Tab->Duplicate Tab
ctrl-shift-T (or whatever you want)
```

[image]